# Set class to Html.DropDownListFor (Razor MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have DropDownList

```
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.English, new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Beginner", Value = "Beginner"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Pre-Intermediate", Value = "Pre-Intermediate"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Intermediate", Value = "Intermediate"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Upper-Intermediate", Value = "Upper-Intermediate"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Advanced", Value = "Advanced"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Proficiency", Value = "Proficiency"}
                }, "Уровень английского")
```

I need to set class to it. How I can do this? `new{@class="class"}` dont works.

Comment: Adding `new { @class = "class" }` as the last parameter (after `"Уровень английского",`) does work! - refer [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor``2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{``0},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0,``1}},System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable{System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem},System.String,System.Object%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried like this ?
See the [documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.English, new[]
{
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Beginner", Value = "Beginner"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Pre-Intermediate", Value = "Pre-Intermediate"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Intermediate", Value = "Intermediate"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Upper-Intermediate", Value = "Upper-Intermediate"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Advanced", Value = "Advanced"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Proficiency", Value = "Proficiency"}
}, "Уровень английского", new { @class = "class" })
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.English, new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Beginner", Value = "Beginner"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Pre-Intermediate", Value = "Pre-Intermediate"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Intermediate", Value = "Intermediate"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Upper-Intermediate", Value = "Upper-Intermediate"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Advanced", Value = "Advanced"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Proficiency", Value = "Proficiency"}
            }, "Уровень английского",new{@class="dropdown"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this format, It is the Simplest code for common, we have accesses anytime

Common.cs:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> LearnerSkill()
    {
           List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
           list.Add(
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Beginner", Value = "Beginner"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Pre-Intermediate", Value = "Pre-Intermediate"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Intermediate", Value = "Intermediate"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Upper-Intermediate", Value = "Upper-Intermediate"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Advanced", Value = "Advanced"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Proficiency", Value = "Proficiency"});
           return list;
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropdownID_or_NAME", Common.LearnerSkill(), new { @class="classname"})

(or)

@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.English, Common.LearnerSkill(), new { @class="classname"})
```